Low disk space after 24 lts upgrade
Due to sudden issue in 22 lts (losing audio, being unable to play video, music or anything in the browser) I opted for upgrading to 24 lts.
Upgrade did solve aformenetioned issues. However I now have an issue of full disk space.
Apart from it, settings are unable to change, any of it. Perhaps its linked to strage issue.
Ubuntu is running of an 120 gb SSD drive, to be more precize out of 95 gb partiton on the drive.
For some reason - UBUNTU / VAR has 69 GB!
sudo apt clean, autoremove ... etc. did nothing.
Thanks in advance for your help,
Stefan

Have you explored what in /var/ is using all that space?  Have you got an unmaintained problem that keeps being reported in a log that no-one does anything about it to fix the problem etc..  The system is seeking maintenance...

To be clear you upgraded a broken system and are surprised it is still broken?

Please try to find which directory in var is taking up so much space and report back. Does sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=20M free up any space?

Thank you for answering.
LOG is taking up almost 65 GB of storage. Files manager wont show what exactly in log takes up so much. There used to be a simple option open as root, but its gone now...
Vacuum removed around 5 gb.
As for the comment on upgrading a broken system. Version 22 was freshly installed and nothing was tinkered with it. It wasnt used for a few months in the meantime. I am really puzzled how anything could have changed, yet alone broke.

found another piece of information - syslog 63.2 gb

You have a runaway logfile.
Your low-space condition is merely a symptom. Some recurring problem is being logged over and over and over, consuming your storage. Fix that underlying problem.

Use tail to read the last 100 or 200 lines of the logfile.
tail -n 200 /var/log/syslog


Fix the actual problem that is being logged over and over.

If you don't understand the log entries, then do a bit of research. Search engines are very good at finding similar text from folks who have had similar output.
If you don't understand the problem, then open a new Question about it.


Delete older logfiles. Don't delete the current logfile.


